# Are Oracle Database CPU license limits enforced by software, and how do I check them?

Tags: oracle, licensing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing issue?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-issue)

I've inherited a windows VM running Oracle Database 10g.  Currently the VM has only one CPU assigned to it, but I can boost this up to 4 with our VMWare licenses.  What I'm not yet certain about is if the Oracle Software will get upset.

Are Oracle DB CPU limits enforced by software, and if so how do I find out what they?  If it's just a legal enforcement I'll hunt through the mass of unsorted paperwork I have left from previous managers to find what we're licensed for, but a quick software check would be nice.

Comment: This is a technical, not legal question; doesn't seem like a duplicate to me.

Comment: confirming this is intended as a technical question; I know how messy the business side of Oracle licensing is and there's no way serverFault can help me out there :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the limits are not enforced by software.  You need to keep track of the licenses you have and the software that is deployed and ensure that you are in compliance.

Note that Oracle does not generally allow you to use VMWare for hard partitioning of a server.  So you would generally need to license every CPU that is on a server where the Oracle VM runs whether or not the Oracle VM is currently able to use those processors.  See the [Oracle Partitioning Policy](http://www.oracle.com/us/corporate/pricing/partitioning-070609.pdf) and/or chat with your local Oracle Sales rep for more details.

Comment: One of the devs said we had some really old grandfathered licensing agreement, so we might not be subject to the license-every-CPU-on-the-hardware... regardless, I need to track down our actual licenses now.